# Does electrical resistance increase with relative velocity due to relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, electrical-resistance, inertial-frames, observers

A spaceship is set up on earth with an RC oscillator driving a LED. It is set to flash once per second. The spaceship accelerates away to a velocity near C and the LED is now seen to be flashing once every 2 seconds due to the slowing of time on the spaceship. If I now calculate the RC time constant I find the resistance must now be double that of what it was when stationary to flash the LED at half the frequency. Is this correct that resistance increases with relative velocity? Can it be observed experimentally?

I see the formula for calculating the resistance of a material shows that resistance is linearly proportional to the mass of the electron, could it be that the increased mass of the electron at the high velocity explains the increase of resistance and the longer RC time constant?

Comment: The geometry of the capacitance will change, which might affect its capacitance differently depending on its orientation - unless something else changes too.

Comment: We could argue that an electrostatic capacitor will change its capacitance differently depending on the orientation. Analogously, we should say that the electrical resistance also changes depending on the orientation. However, it seems that RC will change only depending on the speed and not on the orientation. So, no, there must be some error in this reasoning based on orientation. The question is intriguing!

Answer (score 0):

Circuit theory is inherently a non-relativistic theory. The core assumptions of the theory are violated for relativistically moving circuits. So the question is inherently ill-posed in that sense.

However, there is some effort on generalizing things like Ohm's law into a relativistic framework. Here is an example of the level of detail required in order to do such a thing:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.3723

There is not one simple answer to your question. The relativistic transformation law is much more complicated.